# Column combine two datasets of different size

Tags: sas

I have two datasets of the following structure

```
ID1   Cat1
1     a
2     a
3     b
5     b
5     b
6     c
7     d
```

and

```
ID2   Cat2
11    z
12    z
13    z
14    y
15    x
```

I want to column-combine then and then have the unmatched rows just be missing. So ultimately I want:

```
ID1   Cat1    ID2    Cat2
1     a       11     z
2     a       12     z
3     b       13     z 
4     b       14     y
5     b       15     x
6     c    
7     d
```

The purpose of this is that I have two sorted datasets (by ID) and want to do a matching of the first category (Cat1) with the second (Cat2). The second category has a predefined number of "slots" and those slots should be matched on the order of the IDs. The only relationship between ID1 and ID2 is that they are ordered the same way. So the two lowest should be a match and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a one to one merge.

The documentation is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202970.htm)

In order to do a one to one merge you just need to merge without a `by statement`

This type of merge simply matches the observations based on its row number, so be careful, it may give you unintended results if you are missing a row you thought you had or something else wasn't as you expected.

for example:

```
proc sort data = have1; run;
proc sort data = have2; run;
data want;
   merge have1 have2;
run;
```

Comment: Note that there is an option, `OPTION MERGENOBY`, that controls what happens when you do this (merge without a `by` statement, which is often accidental).  Your system administrator may manage that option, and it may be set to warn you or even throw a hard error if you do this; if you have that issue, and cannot change it yourself, you should talk to your system administrator for workaround options or to change the setting.